# Can’t evolve one of my Pikachu in Pokemon Go

Tags: pokemon-go

I'm fairly new to the game, I have another Pikachu where I have the choice to evolve him but not this one.

[image: Pikachu in Pokemon Go missing evolution button]

Answer (score 10):

This happened because you caught a glitch! A better way of putting it is, if you close down your game and restart it, you'll see this Pikachu is supposed to be wearing a costume. It's a fall event Pikachu, and the costumed Pokemon caught during this event can't be evolved. Since you caught this when your phone didn't have the assets (images etc.) to show the costume, it looked like a regular Pikachu, which should have been evolvable, hence the confusion.

Comment: @YeetMcgee I know you figured it out, just wanted to get a full answer in.